# Have Perl regex match newline followed by tab in macOS

Tags: tabs, newline

I have these two lines in a macOS .plist file:

```
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
```

I want to replace `true` with `false` but only if the preceding line equals `<key>Disabled</key>`.

I know the 1st line ends with `\n` and using Perl I can match/replace it with:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/Disabled<\/key>\n/DISABLED<\/key>\n/g' file
```

Note: I don't want to change `Disabled` to `DISABLED`, this is just to show the match is working.

I know the 2nd line begins with `\t` and I can match/replace it with:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\t<true/\t<false/g' file
```

However, combining the 2 patterns doesn't match/replace anything:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/Disabled<\/key>\n\t<true/Disabled<\/key>\n\t<false/g' file
```

I thought there might be a hidden character between `\n` at the end of the 1st line and `\t`at the beginning of the 2nd line, but I've tried this regex in BBEdit and it works perfectly:

```
Disabled</key>\n\t<true
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear my understanding of Perl is very limited.

After some further digging I now realise that in the code I was using Perl was reading the file line by line. What I needed to do was instruct Perl to read the file in one go or put in another way to "slurp" the file. Using `-0` puts Perl in [file slurp](http://ask.xmodulo.com/search-and-replace-multi-line-string.html) mode.

My original non-working code:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/Disabled<\/key>\n\t<true/Disabled<\/key>\n\t<false/g' file
```

My amended working code using `-0`:

```
perl -0pi -w -e 's/Disabled<\/key>\n\t<true/Disabled<\/key>\n\t<false/g' file
```

To take it one step further I replaced `\n\t` in the match pattern with `(\s*)` so as to match any `space`, `tab` or `newline` character zero or more times and `\n\t` in the replace pattern with `$1`:

```
perl -0pi -w -e 's/Disabled<\/key>(\s*)<true/Disabled<\/key>$1<false/g' file
```

This seems better for matching any number of whitespace characters that appear between the 2 lines.